# How to remove the featured last changed document in a SharePoint Online document library view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

We are using SharePoint Online.
All of a sudden a few weeks ago and without any (consent) action from our side, previews of the last few changed documents in a document library view are added at the top of the list view, above the list of all documents.

How to turn this feature off for
a) a library?
b) the whole site?